# XSSFCell -> how to get interval time value from long

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I got a long value, for example: **44304000**. This value indicates the time interval.
If we convert this value into hours and minutes we got: **12:18**.
My question is here:

How add cell value into XSSFCell when I want to see what my value as time interval? (not as text)

Time - can be calculate via excel, Text - not!

Thx for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your time interval 44304000 is a time difference and is in milliseconds.

In `Excel` date-time values are stored as floating point (`double`) values in measurement unit of days. Day 0 = 1/1/1900 00:00:00.000. So in `Excel` a date-time value of 1.0 means one day. One hour is 1/24. One minute is 1/24/60. One second is 1/24/60/60. One millisecond is 1/24/60/60/1000.

Knowing this, you can calculate

```
double excelTimeIntervalInDays = timeIntervalInMillis/24d/60d/60d/1000d;
```

That `double excelTimeIntervalInDays` can be set as cell value in `Excel`.

Additional an appropriate number format (date format) must be set in cell's cell style, so the `double` value will be shown as time. A number format as `[hh]:mm:ss.000` means: Show two digits hours, even if more than 24 (the brackets set that). Then show `:`. Then show two digits minutes. Then show `:`. Then show two digits seconds. Then show `.`. Then show three digits milliseconds.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelDateTimeFromLong {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   long[] timeIntervalsInMillis = new long[] {
    44304000, //12:18:24.000 = 12h, 18m, 24s
    20*60*60*1000+15*60*1000+10*1000, //20:15:10.000 = 20h, 15m, 10s
    25*60*60*1000+25*60*1000+15*1000, //25:25:15.000 = 25h, 25m, 15s = 1d, 1h, 25m, 15s
    48*60*60*1000+45*60*1000+55*1000, //48:45:55.000 = 48h, 45m, 55s = 2d, 0h, 45m, 55s
   };

   CellStyle timeIntervalStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   timeIntervalStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("[hh]:mm:ss.000"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Time intervals");

   int r = 1;
   for (long timeIntervalInMillis : timeIntervalsInMillis) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r++);
    cell = row.createCell(0);

    double excelTimeIntervalInDays = timeIntervalInMillis/24d/60d/60d/1000d;

    cell.setCellValue(excelTimeIntervalInDays);
    cell.setCellStyle(timeIntervalStyle);
   }

   sheet.setColumnWidth(0,15*256);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Note: This supposes that the `timeIntervalsInMillis` are meant as differences between two dates in milliseconds. Don't confuse that with time stamps in milliseconds. If time stamps are given then a totally different approach is needed since then the epoch of those time stamps must be considered. Then at first dates must be created from that time stamps and those dates must be set as cell values in `Excel`.

Comment: Awesome! It works for me! I got also another question here. I normally use hh:mm and you use [hh]:mm, what made it work! My Poi is on 3.17 version.

Can you send me here a specific format to say: year-month-day hours-minutes-seconds-miliseconds -> as one big format? Thanks to this I will be able to customize it at my app! :)

Comment: @Przemyslaw Beskosty: For possible `Excel` number formats see [Review guidelines for customizing a number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5). For date-time formats open `Guidelines for date and time formats`. But also note my supplement in my answer for not confusing time differences with time stamps.